# How to keep DB connection Active in Spring Batch

Tags: spring, batch-processing

In our Spring Batch Application, We are calling a Stored Procedure. SP is taking 1+ hr to process the Records. In this duration, DB Connection with is opened from the Spring Batch got terminated and We got "Socket Timeout Issue".

Manually, we overcome this Issue by changing the Oracle Parameter - SQLNET.EXPIRE_TIME which keeps the connections active until the processing get over.

Is there any way to do changes in Spring Batch which will keep the Connection Active until the processing get over.

Your Suggestions are much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Ramesh.